# How can I make a MaterialUI form control wider when a value hasn't been selected?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have a  that I am trying to have a  component with certain selections in a dropdown menu. For some reason it's really smashed together, and I'm not sure how to expand the width

Also not sure how to change the font size of "Attributes" as well, tried putting 
`<FormControl style={{fontSize: 12}} />` but that doesn't work

sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-matsumoto-gpgwn

The Component

```
    <div className={styles.attributeFields}>
      <FormControl variant="outlined">
        <InputLabel id="demo-customized-select-label">Attributes</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-customized-select-label"
          id="demo-customized-select"
        >
          <MenuItem value="">
            <em>None</em>
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem>ID</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem>PSA</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem>ExternalID</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
```

And the CSS

```
.attributeFields {
  /* display: inline; */
  width: 100% !important;
  padding-top: 1.75rem !important;
  display: inline-flex !important;
  padding-left: 3% !important;
  padding-bottom: 1rem !important;
}
```

Comment: You need to save your sandbox. It currently just has the default "Hello CodeSandbox" content.

Comment: Also, please include the relevant code in your question text.

Comment: Should be saved now! sorry bout that

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto  fixed what I needed

```
<FormControl style={{ minWidth: '45%' }} />
```